# Delphi XML Parsing and EVariantTypeCastError

Tags: delphi

I'm developing an application which saves and reads preferences to/from XML.  When I add new features, I of course also add the ability to configure these features, but I find that my code crashes when it tries to read variables from XML which don't yet exist.  When this happens, any subsequent variables which should be read are not read, making me lose some of my preferences.  Consider this code as an example:

```
  xmldoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  Try
  xmldoc.LoadFromFile('c:\myxml.xml');
  xmldoc.Active := True;

  if xmldoc.ChildNodes.Count >= 1 then
    Begin
      Control := Root.ChildNodes.FindNode('Control');
      if Assigned(Control) then
      Begin
        Username.Text := Control.Attributes['Username'];
        Password.Text := Control.Attributes['Password'];
        AutoValidate.Checked := Control.Attributes['AutoValidate'];
        AutoIRC.Checked := Control.Attributes['AutoIRC'];
        Passive.Checked := Control.Attributes['Passive'];
        DoNothing.Checked := Control.Attributes['DoNothing'];
        OpenPage.Checked := Control.Attributes['OpenPage'];
        DownloadUsingBrowser.Checked := Control.Attributes['DownloadUsingBrowser'];
        RSSFeed.Checked := Control.Attributes['RSSFeed'];
        SaveToFolder.Checked := Control.Attributes['SaveToFolder'];
        SaveToFTP.Checked := Control.Attributes['SaveToFTP'];
        SavePath.Text := Control.Attributes['SavePath'];
        FTPPath.Text := Control.Attributes['FTPPath'];
      End;
    End;
  Finally
    xmldoc.Active := False;
  End;
```

Assume for a moment that I've just added in "AutoValidate" as an option - the XML file doesn't have this property because it's not yet been saved by the application, but the application still tries to read this property when it launches (reads the preferences).

How can I get it so that missing properties does NOT raise the good old "Exception class EVariantTypeCastError with message 'Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (Boolean)'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test a value of attribute first. You could create an utility function, e.g. like this:

```
function xmlGetBoolAttrValue(ANode:iXMLNode; const AName:String; ADefault:boolean): boolean;
var
  V: variant;
begin
  Result := ADefault;
  if not Assigned(ANode) then
    exit;
  V := ANode.Attributes[AName];
  if VarIsNull(V) then
    exit;
  Result := V;
end;
```

and use it

```
SaveToFTP.Checked := xmlGetBoolAttrValue(Control, 'SaveToFTP', false);
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I tried to edit your answer because you spelled "ADefualt" wrong on the first line.  But edits have to be at least 6 characters!  Perhaps you can edit?

Comment: Thanks muchly, my app is going to be a lot more stable from now on :D